# How to pass SEO Friendly URL Test in open cart

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, opencart

I am using opencart 2.0.1.1 version.
I am creating urls seo friendly...via htaccess and seo keywork enable in admin panel.
it's working fine.

when i am trying to view the product then the url looks like

http://www.example.com/product-name

but same url with this product is hidden like this

http://www.example.com/index.php?route=themecontrol/product&product_id=112

It is hidden url in opencart, i want to disable this url for search engines and i want to pass seo friendly url.

now my website is failed SEO Friendly URL Test

I want to resolve this issue.

The error say's "This analyzed URL is SEO friendly but internal links on this page contain some links that are not SEO
friendly."

How to pass SEO Friendly URL Test .

Answer (score 0):

edit file htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . myfile.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and create file myfile.php

```
<?php
$params     = split("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $params[1];
?>
```

Comment: what was the use of myfile.php and where i can save this file ?